# Can I connect to a 64 bit mysql server from a 32 bit machine with 32 bit mysql client lib?

Tags: mysql, 64-bit

Can I connect to a 64 bit mysql server from a 32 bit machine with 32 bit mysql client lib?

I mean the server is 64 bit version and running on an 64 bit machine and the client app is running on an 32 bit machine with the 32 bit mysql client lib.

Is that OK? Or it will cause some problems?

I don't have two machine so I can't do the test, can some tell me the answer?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Yes. The any difference in bit-ness between the client and the server doesn't matter.